# error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for /, Kind=Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I wrote a Kubernetes Deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-persistence
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: test-persistence
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: test-persistence
      name: test-persistence
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-persistence
          image: ubuntu
          command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /test-persistence
              name: test-persistence
      volumes:
        - name: test-persistence
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-persistence
```

When trying to submit it to my cluster, here is the error I get:

```
$ kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for /, Kind=Deployment
```

## Environment

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.4", GitCommit:"bee2d1505c4fe820744d26d41ecd3fdd4a3d6546", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-12T16:29:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.7-gke.6", GitCommit:"9b635efce81582e1da13b35a7aa539c0ccb32987", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-16T21:33:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Answering my own question*

Following the [documentation example](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#deployment-v1-apps), I replaced

```
apiVersion: v1
```

by

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
```

and it worked just fine afterwards.

Comment: mine won't work even with the "apps/v1"! This works ```apps/v1beta1```

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen might be that you use an old version of Kubernetes where Deployments were not in General Availability

Comment: That would be strange as I am using it from gcp!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen ok I don't know then. Glad you managed to fix it anyway!